# Angular send only changed fields to update method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a save method. On click of a SAVE I only want to send the changed fields instead of everything Since i have more then 50 fields on my page. So its very heavy to send all the fields everytime.

```
Api.Admin.update({
    obsoleteDate : AdminEdit.ObsoleteDate.$dirty== true?$scope.editObsoleteDate:""      
});
```

above I am checking with field dirty value true or false. but i don't want to send value as empty if value is not changed. What other way to that that?

Answer (score 2):

I usually build an object with just the changed properties and send that object. I make a copy of the original object before editing it and then use that to compare, but you could easily adapt this to us $dirty. Something along these lines:

```
function getUpdateObject(orig, current) {
    var changes = {};

    for (var prop in orig) {
        if (prop.indexOf("$") != 0 && orig[prop] !== current[prop]) {
            changes[prop] = current[prop];
        }
    }
    return changes ;
};
```

Then my update code calls this function to get a new object with just my changes, assigns whatever the primary key is from what I'm working with to that object and sends that to the server. I have no idea what your back end is, but you'll most likely need to do an http patch in order for this to work. So something like this:

```
function save() {
    var changes = getUpdateObject(vm.orig, vm.current)
    changes.id = vm.orig.id
    $http.patch("http:/serviceURI.com (" + changes.id + ")", changes).then(...)
}
```

I pulled this code out of an app that uses oData and modified it a bit for this answer, but all of this code exists in a service that I use for all of my oData interactions.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike.. It have changed my code according to your explanation. it worked.. :).. thank You!!

Comment: Great! Feel free to upvote and accept the answer. :)